# Android Database

Tags: android

I am designing an application for an online exam. And I created a database using SQLite Browser and pulled it to Eclipse. In an emulator its working fine; it is able to retrieve and store data. But the problem comes when I place the .apk file on the mobile. On the mobile it's unable to retrieve the existing database. I am unable to bind the database file along with the .apk file, even after placing it in the assets folder.

Can anyone help?

**Details:**

1. Registration module
2. User Test module (display the questions from database)
3. Score submission module

Answer (score 0):

How are you querying on database ?

The correct way is not to place a separate db in your code, but to create one dynamically. For e.g. the following code :

```
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSql("/*Put Create Table sqls here*/");
        //onCreate will be called only once( when db doesn't exists for application, it creates here with the code)
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Use a database helper class like this in your code.

Now whenever you want to query on your db you can do it like this :

```
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(ctx);
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    //Start querying on db.(if it is not created oncreate() of dbhelper will create it for you.
```

So simply put your initial db create,/insert statements in oncreate() of dbhelper